# Refreshing Excel Pivot having Data Connection with SQL Server

Tags: excel, vba

I have created an excel pivot table which fetches the data from SQL Query/View. I would like to refresh this file with specific interval and hence written a vba script as under:

```
Option Explicit
Dim XlApp,XlBook
Set XlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set XlBook = XlApp.Workbooks.open("E:\Data\FF Reports\Conversion.xlsx")
XLApp.Visible = False
XlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
XlApp.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
XlBook.Refreshall
XlApp.Wait 30000
XlBook.Save()
XlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close = True
XlApp.Quit
```

The property of file shows the current date and time when we run this script, but it is not refreshing the data.

Can some one guide me?

Comment: I suggest you specifically refresh the pivottable rather than using `RefreshAll`.

Comment: Thanks. Will Try. However, if I use Refreshall on data tab in workbook, it refreshes the data.